# different css for different links in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I generated a basic toy app using scaffolding and I have the following link in it

```
    <td><%= link_to image_tag("show.png"), note%><%= link_to 'Show', note %></td>
```

so both the image and the text are links to the same page.
the basic css for a comes with

```
  &:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
  }
```

I tried to find a way to keep this for the text part, but eliminate it for the image link , bt I could not find a way

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign a class (e.g. "icon") to the image link:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("show.png"), note, :class => 'icon' %>
<%= link_to 'Show', note %>
```

And then declare the `:hover` CSS for the image link separately from the text link which hasn't been assigned the class:

```
a {
  &.icon {
    &:hover {
      /* declarations here */
    }
  }
}
```

It is likely that you will have different styles for different kinds of image links anyway.